# How do I relate new data to a currently logged in user in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to add a student list to my Firebase realtime database. When a teacher adds a new student, I want the currently logged-in teachers ID to relate to the student they just added.

When I compile the following I get my "Student Added" toast on the emulator but nothing shows up on Firebase - no new parent of "students" and no new entries. Can someone see where I'm going wrong?

I think using datasnapshot to get thecurrentUserId from Firebase might be long-winded but when I just used the simpler .getCurrentUser().getUid() I was getting the same result, successful toast but nothing showing in the Firebase database.

```
package com.example.dissertation814.teacher.studentlist;

import java.util.Objects;

public class AddStudentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//firebase auth
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

//navigation variables
public String currentUserAccount;
public String teacherAccountNav = "Teacher";

//user id from firebase
public String currentUserId;

//add student variables
EditText editTextName;
EditText editTextEmail;
Button buttonAddStudent;

DatabaseReference databaseStudents;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_student);

    //initialise views
    editTextName = findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    buttonAddStudent = findViewById(R.id.addStudentButton);

    //get current user id from firebase
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String uid = Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    DatabaseReference userIdDetails = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid);
    userIdDetails.keepSynced(true);

    //addlistener for current user id
    userIdDetails.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            currentUserId = dataSnapshot.child("userId").getValue().toString();
            //creates new node 'students' linked to 'userId' of current user
            databaseStudents = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("students").child(currentUserId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    //calls addStudent method when clicked
    buttonAddStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addStudent();
        }
    });
}

//add new student method
private void addStudent(){
    String studentName = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String studentEmail = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(studentName)){
        //this string is getting the id from firebase
        String id = databaseStudents.push().getKey();

        Student student = new Student(id, studentName, studentEmail);

        //this sets the student at the child from the id
        //use this to set student at the child for the current user
        databaseStudents.child(id).setValue(student);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Student Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Name required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: try this `databaseStudents.child(currentUserId).setValue(student);`

Comment: What's the problem when you run this code? For example: does the student not get written to the database at all? Or does it get written, but not with any relation to the teacher?

Comment: The student doesn't get written to the database at all.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the student doesn't get written to the database at all. A new 'students' node is not even created. But I can't see why not? ` databaseStudents = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("students").child(currentUserId);` this should create it but it's not.

Comment: Did you check your logcat output for any error messages when `setValue(student)` runs.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no error messages in my logcat for that line or any other lines that I can see. I get my confirmation toast but nothing adds or creates in my Realtime Database.

Comment: The two most commons reasons for data not being written are: 1) your security rules rejecting it, in which case you'd see an error message in the logcat output (or by attacking a completion/failure listener), 2) your app not being connected to Firebase, which is not an error condition as Firebase will then write it to the database once it reconnects. I'm not sure which one of these (of either) you are getting though.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm getting this: W/RepoOperation: setValue at /students/lKZ3Dpx59BgslzdVmvFqZOM6ux52/-MBpeXceqnBa1juZ9SA0 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied. I don't understand how permission is denied though as I have a test user authorised on the app when I log in. Do I have to provide Firebase Auth code somewhere in the AddStudentActivity too?

Comment: The security rules for your database don't allow the operation. It's impossible to say more at this point. But please read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) and [search for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+permission+denied), as there are a lot of cases describing what causes this error message.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks that fixed it. I changed the rules to allow authenticated users to read/write.